# friends count in header of social network

Tags: database, laravel, relationships

I'm still learning in Laravel and as project I chose my Social Network which I already have in CodeIgniter.

Someone who has more experience in Laravel as me recommended me to use in my header.blade this. Auth()->User()->GetFriendsCount()

My Users Model

```
public function friends()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Friends', 'receiver_id');
}

public function GetFriendsCount()
{
    return $this->friends->count(); //didn't help
    return $this->friends()->count(); //didn't help
}
```

I get following as error Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::GetFriendsCount()

Who can help me and how will I reach my result?

Comment: Have you tried `return count($this->friends)` ? This one `return $this->friends()->count();` should work though.

Comment: This error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::GetFriendsCount()` suggests you're calling the method GetFriendsCount() on a query builder object so I think there may be something wrong with how you're calling the method as it doesn't appear you're calling it on the User object

Comment: Try` $friends = Auth()->User()->friends; if($friends) $total_friends = $friends->count();`

Comment: You have to ->get() the friends... Try ```return count($this->friends()->get());```

Comment: Auth() isn't a method, it's a class, try ```Auth::user()->getFriendsCount()``` also change function name to getFriendsCount() as psr standards to start with lowercase.

Comment: nothing helps. it stays at the message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getFriendsCount()'

Answer (score 0):

> if you not connected Auth()->User() return null

```
<?php   
if(Auth()->User())
    dd(Auth()->User()->GetFriendsCount());
else dd('not connect');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code out:

User model:

```
public function friends()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Friends', 'receiver_id');
}

public function getFriendsCount()
{
    return $this->friends()->count();
}
```

Try playing around with an instance of the model in `artisan tinker` before running it in your view. You could do something like this:

```
php artisan tinker // get into tinker

$u = App\Models\User::first(); // grab the first user in the db, they should have some App\Models\Friends linked to them

$u->getFriendsCount(); // test out the method
```

You can run the method in your blade view like so:

```
Auth::user()->getFriendsCount()
```

Comment: I got this as result.
>>> $u->getFriendsCount();
=> ←[35m4←[39m

It doesn't help.

The thing is if I write the complete query into the header, then I get the result which I want. If I write the same query into the model then I get the same error 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getFriendsCount()'

Comment: Try playing around with both the relationship call `->friends` and the method in tinker I'm sure you'd work it out then. Sorry can't help you debug further right now.